python copy excel conserving exactly the same parameters in the doc (style, cells size and fusion, borders...)
I am looking for a method to copy and excel in an other file. I have a 'file_1.xlsx', and I would like a 'file_1_copy.xlsx' that is not existing. The copy has to be exactly the same that the original file, it means the cells size, their fusion, the color of the text in the cells, the background, if there are borders, as if I did a copy of the doc with the right click.
I have that :
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test excel.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        new_cell = new_ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.col_idx, value=cell.value)
        if cell.has_style:
            new_cell.font = Font(name=cell.font.name, size=cell.font.size, bold=cell.font.bold, italic=cell.font.italic, color=cell.font.color)

new_wb.save('test copie excel.xlsx')


So on the images, on the left it is the original file. On the right the copy, but the text in the first cell is supposed to be in 2 colors : right and blue, and overlighted in yellow. Or in the copy, I got only one color, all the text became red, and is not overlight anymore.
Does it exist a simple method to copy an excel as if it was done at the hand with a right click, that will copy exactly the original file and all its attributes / elements inside ?

Just use wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test excel.xlsx') to load the work book to copy from. and then use wb.save('test copie excel.xlsx') to save the file under a new file name.

I tried, the text is overlighted in yellow so for that it's ok, but all the text in the cell becomes red, I loose the 2 colors for the text

Maybe rich_text flag in the answer post will solve your issue.

Excel cells normally have only one font. If there is text in rich text format in Excel cells, then the cell content itself is rich text cell content. But rich text cell content is not read while load workbook file per default for performance reasons. So one must set rich_text=True in load_workbook('test excel.xlsx', rich_text=True) if needed.
The color is the fill color of the cell. To keep this, the fill must also be copied.
Btw.: There is copy from copy which can be used to copy whole cell.font and cell.fill to avoid the need to copy each single font- and fill-property.
And the column widths are worksheet dimensions settings, which needs to be set for the new_ws too if they shall be the same.
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from copy import copy

wb = load_workbook('test excel.xlsx', rich_text=True)
ws = wb.active

new_wb = Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        new_cell = new_ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.col_idx, value=cell.value)
        new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
        new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)

for column_name in ws.column_dimensions:
    new_ws.column_dimensions[column_name].width = ws.column_dimensions[column_name].width
            
new_wb.save('test copie excel.xlsx')

That is for cell- and worksheet-properties you have now. if the need is copying all possible cell- and worksheet-properties, then the code gets very long and complex.
Above code works using openpyxl version 3.1.2. Version 3.1.3 seems to have bugs while copying rich text from shared-strings into inline-strings when text runs contain spaces only. Then the XML for the text should be <t xml:space="preserve"> </t> but is <t> </t> using Version 3.1.3. That leads to an error while opening the file in Excel.
But would not using another approach more convenient?
Open the test excel.xlsxusing wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test excel.xlsx', rich_text=True). Then do the needed changing in wb. After all use wb.save('test copie excel.xlsx') to save the file under a new file name. No need for new_wb and new_ws at all.

Thanks, it works, yes just use 'wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test excel.xlsx', rich_text=True)' and 'wb.save('test copie excel.xlsx')' perfectly works
